# Insure MBP against theft/breakage

Tags: macbook-pro

I don't have home contents cover. Anyone know of a good, reliable insurer for a MBP?

I've read up on AppleCare but it doesn't include theft cover (as far as I can tell?)... I'd need this sort of cover as it's my major concern aside dropping it.

Comment: Voted to close due as this "question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

Comment: it's fine I found the perfect company on a a different Apple forum.

Comment: I think this is a good question; just because it doesn't apply to you, doesn't mean it is too localised ;-).

Comment: @g - however when the OP said and asked for a UK insurer it was closed as for a small geographic are - but leaving it for US answers seems OK - either both or neither should be closed

Comment: @AlexW, care to share which company you picked and your opinion?

Comment: I used a company called Protect Your Bubble http://www.protectyourbubble.com/

Answer (score 4):

AppleCare definitely doesn't cover theft. In fact, AppleCare doesn't even cover accidental damage like dropping it, spilling liquid on it, etc.

There are two companies that I hear about from other Mac users where the stories have been positive. Mind you I've never used either company so have no idea how their service is or anything.

For accidental damage plus the normal manufacturer's defect coverage provided by AppleCare I've heard good things about **[Square Trade](http://www.squaretrade.com/pages/applecare)**. This is the company I've heard the most good about, but they don't provide theft coverage. Square Trade is available only in the United States and Canada.

For accidental damage plus theft (not clear if it covers standard warranty-type damage) I've heard some good about **[Safeware](http://www.safeware.com/Products/IndividualCoverage.aspx)**. I haven't heard as much about them, but a lot of folks have theft coverage through their homeowner's insurance or their renter's insurance, so not at many people need a separate policy. Safeware is available only in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have renters or home owners insurance? your broker may be able to track down a rider you can attach to those policies to provide specific coverage for a laptop. You may have to dance a bit if the device is used entirely for work at the work premises, or if it is work related for your home business.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his first sentence, "I don't have home contents cover," is UK-speak for not having that insurance, though I'm not certain.

Comment: Yep that's right @Matthew